# Error in OkHttp instantiating in Android

Tags: android, okhttp

I am facing the following error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3.internal.tls.OkHostnameVerifier
```

when I want to develop a connection with the database using **OkHttpClient**.

I have included the following dependency in gradle;
    `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'`

Comment: post your `build.gradle` and class where you are using OkHttp.

Comment: u also need to add compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'

Answer (score 2):

I didn't have enough reputation points to post it as a comment. So, I'm writing it out as answer. Other answers didn't work for me. I already have both okhttp3 and okio dependencies in my build.gradle.
It's not an exact answer but analysis of the issue as even I had the exact same issue. So, I tried to debug it somewhat.

Stacktrace :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3.internal.tls.OkHostnameVerifier
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:364)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:151)
```

So, I decompiled my APK and found that OkHostnameVerifier class was not present in my APK, even though it's present in the [source of Okhttp3](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/internal/tls/OkHostnameVerifier.java). So, may be gradle is removing those files, thinking of them as unused code, a false positive.

But if I enable the minifyEnabled in the build.gradle, it fixes that issue and keeps all those class files in the APK.
So, I think it's a bug in proguard.

Comment: Maybe it was a proguard issue?

Comment: @Mauker Right, proguard issue, not gradle. Thanks for correcting!

Answer (score 1):

For the `OkHttp` library to work, you have to include those two dependencies on your `build.gradle` file:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.8.0'
```

Alternatively, you can download the [OkHttp jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.3.1/okhttp-3.3.1.jar) **AND** the [Okio jar](https://search.maven.org/remote_content?g=com.squareup.okio&a=okio&v=LATEST), and put those under your `libs` folder.

For more information, please visit the [OkHttp page](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) and the [Okio page](https://github.com/square/okio).